# Error: type error near ... ; current type... ; expected type

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I want to input data from r_D1_1 and r_D2_1 (these are outputs from a separate entity and continually change) into r_wave0 and r_wave1 respectively and I have tried doing the following:

```
r_wave0 <= r_D1_1 ;
r_wave1 <= r_D2_1 ;
```

This has resulted in the error (I have shown the error for the first line as the 2nd line is the same other than swapped input):

```
Error : type error near r_D1_1 ; current type integer ; expected type t_wave
```

As previously highlighted, the inputs are not fixed and so I wanted to assign them to r_wave0 and r_wave1 as they were generated. Should I overhaul the way I am creating the other arrays and 'calling' the input or maybe I shouldn't be labelling them as " in integer range 0 to 256 " and instead using SLVs?

All feedback is appreciated, thank you!

Below is a copy of the code for the entire entity.

```
entity Demodulator_A is
Port (  i_Clk : in STD_LOGIC;
    i_Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    r_D2_1 : in integer range 0 to 256;
    r_D1_1 : in integer range 0 to 256;
    final_D2 : out integer range 0 to 256;
    final_D1 : out integer range 0 to 256 );
end Demodulator_A;

architecture Behavioral of Demodulator_A is

type t_waveform1 is array (0 to 7) of integer; -- Array for reference waveform '1'
signal r_waveform1 : t_waveform1  := (16#80#, 16#60#, 16#40#, 16#60#, 16#80#, 16#A0#, 16#C0#, 16#A0#);
signal r_demodulated1 : t_waveform1;

type t_waveform0 is array (0 to 7) of integer; -- Array for reference waveform '0'
signal r_waveform0 : t_waveform0  := (16#80#, 16#A0#, 16#C0#, 16#A0#, 16#80#, 16#60#, 16#40#, 16#60#);
signal r_demodulated0 : t_waveform0;

type t_wave is array (0 to 7) of integer;
signal r_wave0 : t_wave ;
signal r_wave1 : t_wave ;
 
begin

DeModulationProc : process (i_Clk)
begin 
    if (r_wave0(2)>=16#81#) then
        r_demodulated0 <= r_waveform0;
    elsif (r_wave1(2)<=16#7F#) then
        r_demodulated1 <= r_waveform1;
    end if;
end process;

--0 = 80, A0, C0, A0, 80, 60, 40, 60. -- in hex the waveform values for 0
--1 = 80, 60, 40, 60, 80, A0, C0, A0. -- in hex the waveform values for 1

end Behavioral;
```

EDIT 1: I am trying to assign 1 changing integer to a whole array and it's causing problems so I want to assign the first integer to the first element of the array, the 2nd integer to the 2nd element and so on. From a comment I now know I could address the array with a counter and this counter could increment every time the input values changes. I will upload this code once I have written it to help others. Thank you Brian!

EDIT 2: I did have 2 libraries listed but forgot to include them in the above code snippet. Below are the two I used.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
```

Comment: Your code tries to assign one integer to the whole of an 8-element array of integers. That clearly won't work, but to move forward you need to know what you actually intended to do...

Comment: Hi Brian, so how would I assign the first integer to the first element of the array, the 2nd integer to the 2nd element and so on? I thought it would shift through and add each new integer to a new element.

Comment: (That's a detail that ought to be in the question!) Address the array with a counter that increments every time a new sample comes in.

Comment: You're missing a context clause (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`) before the entity declaration. Adding that and your code analyzes (compiles), it's valid VHDL although `r_D2_1` is never evaluated. Identify the source of the error message (the tool and version). Is the error from the same code shown here?

Comment: @user1155120 hi, sorry I didn't include the libraries in the above extract but I do have some in my code, I'll put them in now!